# Accessing 'Tkinter' buttons found in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm working on creating a 'checkers' like grid using tkinter buttons. I have successfully created each button with the right colours, using a class and a for loop. I have assigned, at least tried, a name to each button and stored it in a dictionary. My question is now - how do I modify a specific button found in that dictionary? let's say for example using the '.configure()' functions to change the buttons text or something. Is there a way or do I need to re-write my code in a different way?

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import sys

class Checkers:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("A simple GUI")
        master.geometry("752x689")
        master.configure(bg="grey90")
        master.resizable(0, 0)

    def create_button(self, msg, setBg, x, y):
        self.bttn1 = Button(self, text=msg, width=12, height=5, bg=setBg)
        self.bttn1.grid(row=x, column=y)


def draw():

    root = Tk()
    app = Checkers(root)
    y = -1
    d ={}

    for z in range(8):
        y += 1
        for x in range(8):
            if  (y % 2) == 1 and (x % 2) == 1:
                d["button{}{}".format(x,y)] = Checkers.create_button(root, '', 'grey90', x, y)
                print(y,x)
            if  (y % 2) == 1 and (x % 2) == 0:
                d["button{}{}".format(x,y)] = Checkers.create_button(root, '', 'grey60', x, y)
                print(y,x)
            if  (y % 2) == 0 and (x % 2) == 1:
                d["button{}{}".format(x,y)] = Checkers.create_button(root, '', 'grey60', x, y)
                print(y,x)
            if (y % 2) == 0 and (x % 2) == 0:
                print(y,x)
                d["button{}{}".format(x,y)] = Checkers.create_button(root, '', 'grey90', x, y)


    root.mainloop()

draw()
```

Comment: Creating a string name for each button in the dictionary is just making more work for you.  Use a tuple as the key: `d[x,y]`.

Comment: ... or a nested dictionary, or just a nested list (since you have "dense" integer indices anyway)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use tuples instead of computed strings

I recommend using a tuple rather than a string as an index. For example:

```
...
d[(x,y)] = Checkers.create_button(...)
...
```

Later, to modify something you just have to give it the column and row. For example, to modify the button at 4,6 it's just:

```
d[(4,6)].configure(...)
```

### Another problem

You also have the problem that `create_button` isn't returning the button. It needs to return the button so that you can configure it.

```
def create_button(self, msg, setBg, x, y):
    ...
    return self.bttn1
```

### A better solution

Even better would be for your `Checkers` class to maintain the list of buttons, and have it provide a method for updating a button. Then your application doesn't have to "know" that the checkers class is using a button.

For example:

```
class Checkers():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.buttons = {}
        ...
    def create_button(self, msg, setBg, x, y):
        button = Button(self, text=msg, width=12, height=5, bg=setBg)
        button.grid(row=x, column=y)
        self.buttons[(x,y)] = button

    def update_button(self, x, y, text):
        self.buttons[(x,y)].configure(text=text)
```

Then, anywhere in your code that you need to update a button, you call the `update_button` method on the `Checkers` instance:

```
app = Checkers(root)
...
app.update_button(4,6, "hello, world")
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created buttons dynamically before, but I used a list instead. If you want to use `.configure()` with a dictionary, use the grid coordinates you used to specify the button (x, y).

```
def modify(x, y):
    d['button%s%s' % (x, y)].configure(...)
```

An example of dynamically creating buttons with lists: (In a class)

```
def initialize(self, index):
    self.indexNum = index
    self.questions[self.indexNum] = tk.Button(...)
    self.questions[self.indexNum].place(x = widgetPositions[0], y = widgetPositions[1]) #This is just a tuple of grid positions
```

self.questions was created in the `__init__` section of the class, and stores a list of button objects. The index just specifies which button is to be assigned. By the same method, you can access the button for your purposes, to configure it.

Please comment if you have any questions.

Comment: I am completely lost, I have tried using 'd['button%s%s' % (1, 0)].configure(text='modified')' just to see if it would work and got an error - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'configure'. The idea of using lists instead totally lost me too, Im sorry I'm still quite new to this language :/.

Comment: Even though you probably already have the answer, you got the error 'NoneType' because you created the button and assigned it a grid position on the same line.